# BPY Layout difference between various enum methods

Tags: python, scripting

I am unable to find a good reference on where to use these following methods of bpy.types.UILayout even in official bpy documentation.

1. operator_enum
2. operator_menu_enum
3. props_enum
4. prop_menu_enum
5. prop_enum
6. prop_tabs_enum

Can anyone please help in understanding where each of it can be used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## prop_*

The `prop_*` methods are for controlling the value of a property on a data object.

#### prop_enum

```
layout.prop_enum(light, "type", 'POINT')
layout.prop_enum(light, "type", 'SUN')
```

[image]

Creates one button. Pressing the button sets the property to the given value (eg. the first button does `light.type = 'POINT'`). The button lights up to show when the property is equal to the given value.

#### props_enum

```
layout.props_enum(light, "type")
```

[image]

Creates a button for each enum value. That is, it loops over all the enum values and does `prop_enum` for each one.

#### prop_tabs_enum

```
layout.prop_tabs_enum(light, "type")
```

[image]

Similar to `props_enum`, but creates a horizontal row of tabs for each enum value.

#### prop

```
layout.prop(light, "type")
```

[image]

The generic property control. For enums, creates a combo box (drop down menu).

#### prop_menu_enum

```
layout.prop_menu_enum(light, "type")
```

[image]

Another combo box, but not the same as `prop`?

---

---

## operator_*

`operator_*` methods, on the other hand, are for calling an operator, passing the value of an enum as a parameter.

#### operator_enum

```
layout.operator_enum("object.light_add", "type")
```

[image]

Creates a button for each enum value. Clicking a button calls the operator with that parameter (eg. the first button calls `bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='POINT')`).

#### operator_menu_enum

```
layout.operator_menu_enum("object.light_add", "type")
```

[image]

Creates a drop down menu. Clicking an entry in the drop down menu calls the operator with that parameter.

Comment: +1 ....this should be part of the documentation!

Comment: prop_menu_enum seems like it is well suited for flag enums (enums where multiple values are valid)